# How can I make an RPM depend on package a OR package b?

Tags: dependencies, rpm, requires

This seems like a simple question, but [the docs](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html) don't seem to have anything to say on the subject.  I would like to do something like `Requires: vim or emacs` but when I do that, I in fact depend on `vim`, `or` and `emacs`.  What is the syntax for depending on one or another of two packages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The standard way to do this is via virtual provides: the providing RPMs each state that they provide a virtual package, and the dependent RPM requires that virtual package.  So, in your example, `vim` and `emacs` both `Provides: text-editor`, and your package would `Requires: text-editor`.

If the packages that you're depending on don't provide an appropriate virtual package, you could probably hack around this by making up your own.  Make dummy `my-package-vim-mode` and `my-package-emacs-mode` RPMs that `Requires: vim` and `Requires: emacs`, respectively, and `Provides: my-package-text-editor`, then have your package `Requires: my-package-text-editor`.

Answer (score 8):

If packages don't have common Provide, and you don't want to rebuild and maintain forks of that packages, but they both do provide same file, you can depend on a file. For example:

```
Requires: /usr/bin/pear
```

That way your package won't matter if pear binary is provided by php-pear or php53-pear.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such capability in rpm. Require a virtual provides that the packages have in common, if there is one.