# RPM Spec file requiring MySQL or MariaDB

Tags: mysql, dependencies, mariadb, rpm, requires

I have a spec file that currently requires mysql packages. I now have a requirement to require either mysql or MariaDB. But, I'm not sure how to set up such an OR releationship in my .spec file. I am somewhat familiar with the virtual "Provides" piece, but I am not sure if these mysql and equivilant mariadb packages provide the same thing.

```
%if 0%{?build6}
Requires        : mysql-server, mysql, ...
%endif

%if 0%{?build7}
Requires        : mysql-community-server, mysql-community-client, ...
%endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an RPM depend on package a OR package b?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139621/how-can-i-make-an-rpm-depend-on-package-a-or-package-b)

Answer (score 1):

RPM `Requires` entries *do not* support OR logic. The RPM solution to that problem *is* "virtual" `Provides` entries.

You will need to look at the appropriate MySQL and MariaDB packages and compare the list of things they provide and look for something appropriate to `Require`.

That's the only correct solution possible.

Comment: OK, do you know how to go about looking at the packages for what they provide?

Comment: Also, what if they don't provide the same things?

Comment: `rpm -qp --provides "$package.rpm"` will list the provides from an RPM file. `rpm -q --provides "$pkgname"` will list the provides for an installed package. You have to hope that they do because if they don't then you can't do this in a correct fashion and you get to use one of a number of awful workarounds.

Comment: OK, I checked MariaDB-10.1.8-centos6-i686-server.rpm   and mysql-community-server-5.7.9-1.el7.i686.rpm. They both provide mysql-server. But, only the mysql rpm provides mysql-community server. 

I believe I can just remove the "-community" portion of the centos7 requirements.