# Should I still declare Requires dependencies for other shared objects?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

One of the interesting features of RPM is that it will look at shared objects, find out what they're linked against, find out what packages provide those linked shared libraries, and automatically install those dependent libraries as part of the installation of the compiled shared library.

If libnaftuli is linked against libbz2, for instance, rpm-build will specify the dependency in the libnaftuli RPM without my having to declare it in my .spec file.

Should I still declare those dependencies in my spec file then? I suppose that I should declare ambiguous dependencies, but otherwise should I still manually figure out what my libraries link against and specify their requires clauses, or just let rpm-build be smart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic dependencies added by `rpmbuild` are helpful, but they do not do everything.  Explicit `Requires` tags can do these extra things:

- tell `rpm` that it is okay to install your package with specific versions (including a range of versions) of a given dependency.
- tell `rpm` that the package depends upon a *virtual* package, e.g., a package which provides the "same" functionality but under different names (such as saying *any* Java package).

Further reading:

- [Manual Dependencies](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html) (Maximum RPM)
- [How can I make an RPM depend on package a OR package b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139621/how-can-i-make-an-rpm-depend-on-package-a-or-package-b)
- [Creating a Virtual Java RPM](http://stevenengelhardt.com/2013/05/29/creating-a-virtual-java-rpm/)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed.

Answer (score 1):

If you require some other package *solely* because of a library requirement that rpm figures out for you then no there isn't really any reason to list the package as a requirement yourself manually.

If, however, you depend on that package for some *other* reason (non-library file, etc.) or have specific versioning requirements on the package (which library versioning should generally handle for you so you shouldn't) then adding it yourself makes sense.

Any *other* packages you have requirements on, that rpm doesn't pick up, should obviously be listed explicitly.